# PDO multiple select issue

Tags: php, pdo

I am inserting a form multiple select value in my database but it only inserts the last selected value. How can I solve this here is my code. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code and why it is only inserting last value. Thanks

PHP:

```
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO portfolio (title, descrption,categories,skill, images) VALUES (:title, :editor1,:Category,:skill,:fileToUpload)");    
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
        $stmt->bindParam(':editor1', $dec);        
        $stmt->bindParam(':skill',$value);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Category',$cat);
        $stmt->bindParam(':fileToUpload',$pic);    
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $dec = $_POST['editor1'];
        $skill=$_POST['skill'];       
        foreach ($skill as $value)
        {
            echo $value;
        }
        $cat= $_POST['Category'];
        $pic=($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);

        $stmt->execute();
        echo "Portfolio records created successfully";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Skills</label>
    <select id="ms" name="skill[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option>Html5</option>
        <option>Css3</option>
        <option>Illustrator</option>
        <option>Photoshop</option>
        <option>Coral Draw</option>
        <option>Jquery</option>
        <option>Javascript</option>
        <option>Wordpress</option>
        <option>Magento</option>
        <option>Android</option>
        <option>Woocommerce</option>
        <option>PHP</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see your form?

Comment: You have to give values in the option tag as well for example: 

<option value="Html5" >Html5</option> so when it is submitted the value will be saved in variable

Comment: You are binding with `$stmt->bindParam(':skill',$value);` but how and where are you initializing `$value`?

Comment: I tried       $skill=$_POST['skill'];       
      foreach ($skill as $value)
    {
    echo $value;
    } when I echo $value it show me all values

Comment: Do you know that you have to initialize a variable **before** you use it, e.g. `$value = 'test'; $stmt->bindParam(':skill',$value);` and not `$stmt->bindParam(':skill',$value); $value = 'test';`?

Comment: Could you please update the code I still get the last selected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly insert an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) like `$_POST['skill']` into a database field, but you can for instance join the values inside the array into a string and insert the string into the database field.

So you can try something like this:

```
$skills = join(',', $_POST['skill']);
$stmt->bindParam(':skill', $skills);
```

Of course some other approaches are possible (like inserting the different values into different rows/datasets of the database table).

Comment: Thanks  Working for me